# How to write and compile a mixed programming language (C and FORTRAN) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Basically I wanted to write a mixed-programming language using C and FORTRAN in Eclipse(Parallel Application Development) IDE in Ubuntu(Linux Environment).

My main program would be in C and calling functions would be in FORTRAN. Now how should I link this FORTRAN source programs to the C project?

I was able to write and compile the same (mixed-programming) from terminal(linux) with out any issue.

Comment: I've had little success doing this with Eclipse; I've had a lot more luck with NetBeans.

Comment: @EliLansey Hi! how did you add/link fortran source code to the c source code?

Comment: Although your question is for Eclipse, I'll write an answer shortly for NetBeans.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: @EliLansey Linux(Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

Comment: An old tool is f2c. I don't know whether it satisfies your interests.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have appropriate compilers installed; usually the default GNU compiler collection (but this works just as well with Intel's compilers). Ensure that you have both a C (gcc) and Fortran (gfortran) compiler installed. In [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), make sure the compilers are recognized. Go to Tools --> Options, and select the C/C++ tab. The C, C++, and Fortran compilers should be listed there. If they're not, click the "Restore Defaults" button and it should find them.

Next, make a new C/C++ project (File -->  New Project), selecting "C/C++ Application". Click "Next". Fill out the info for Project Name, location, folder, etc. Check the box that says "Create Main File" and make sure that 'C' is selected from the drop down menu on the right. Click "Finish".

At this point you should have a "Hello World" C code that compiles. Check this: Run --> Clean and Build Project. Then run it.

To add a Fortran (or another C/C++) source file, right click on "Source Files" in the "Projects" window on the left and click "New" and select the appropriate file type (Fortran, for this example). Give it a file name, and select if it's an F or F90 (or any of the other options) type file. This will automatically add it to the build and linking. You can also add an existing file by selecting the "Add Existing Item..." option.

It is likely that you'll need to include some standard Fortran libraries when linking. To do this, right click on the project name and select "Properties". On the menu at the left, click on "Linker". Add additional library directories as needed (2nd line) and on the 2nd to last line you can add particular libraries -- add any Fortran libraries (IO is one common one) you need for the Fortran file.

At this point, you should be able to compile the mixed source code without any trouble. If you want to call the Fortran subroutine from C, make sure you have an appropriate header file (which you can add by right-clicking on "Header Files" and selecting "New" --> "C Header file") which contains the `extern "C" void functionname(arguments)` for any subroutine in the Fortran file.

Comment: Just to note, this works on Fedora and Windows (using MinGW compilers).